# Could not connect to host (http://localhost:18083/)

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

Ubuntu 22.04

VBox ver: 7.0.12r159484

phpvirtualbox ver: latest

I get this error when trying to login on virtualbox using phpvirtualbox GUI.
Any help is highly appreciated, I'm still a junior. Below you find everything you would need
Error:

```
Exception Object
(
    [message:protected] => Could not connect to host (http://127.0.0.1:18083/)
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 64
    [file:protected] => /var/www/html/phpvirtualbox/endpoints/api.php
    [line:protected] => 134
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

config.php:

```php
/* Username / Password for system user that runs VirtualBox */
var $username = 'admin';
var $password = 'admin';

/* SOAP URL of vboxwebsrv (not phpVirtualBox's URL) */
var $location = 'http://127.0.0.1:18083/';

/* Default language. See languages folder for more language options.
 * Can also be changed in File -> Preferences -> Language in
 * phpVirtualBox.
 */
var $language = 'en';

/* Set the standard VRDE Port Number / Range, e.g. 1010-1020 or 1027 */
var $vrdeports = '9000-9100';
/* Set the default VRDE address, e.g. 192.168.1.1 */
#var $vrdeaddress = '192.168.1.1';
```

```bash
cat /etc/default/virtualbox
VBOXWEB_USER=vbox
VBOXWEB_HOST=127.0.0.1
VBOXWEB_PORT=18083
```

```bash
root@daspletosaurus /var/www/html/phpvirtualbox # systemctl status vboxweb-service
● vboxweb-service.service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxweb-service.sh; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Mon 2023-11-13 09:31:34 UTC; 1h 10min ago
        CPU: 3ms

Nov 13 09:31:34 daspletosaurus systemd[1]: Starting vboxweb-service.service...
Nov 13 09:31:34 daspletosaurus systemd[1]: Started vboxweb-service.service.
```

permissions:

```bash
drwxr-xr-x 10 www-data vboxusers  4096 Nov 13 10:36 phpvirtualbox/
```

tried disabling auth, i get another error
tried install/reinstall

What is expected?

Succesfull Login to phpvirtualbox